# How devise stores and read salts/hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

How does it work, that devise knows salts for encrypted passwords? Where does it store these hashes and how is that safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the main files for creating passwords: [Devise::DatabaseAuthenticatable](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/13e1a8fd8c3426d1417ee033d7c50e076c6d87e9/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb)

Salt is not stored in the database, it is a string generated by this C program that is run by the `BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt()` function `__bc_salt`:

```
 prefix = "$2a$05$CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC.E5YPO9kmyuRGyh0XouQYb4YMJKvyOeW"
 __bc_salt(prefix, cost, OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes(MAX_SALT_LENGTH))
```

This can be found here: 
[BCrypt::Engine](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/blob/9926a7b5bf312369f8a7ff9606b453a2c185637d/lib/bcrypt/engine.rb)

With some other interesting code here: [BCrypt::Password](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/blob/9926a7b5bf312369f8a7ff9606b453a2c185637d/lib/bcrypt/password.rb)

From what I can gather though, the salt itself is the 29 characters that appear after the third $ in the encrypted password. This alone cannot tell you the password though, since you also need to know the `pepper` which is based on your apps secret key (usually stored in your `/config/initializers/secret_token.rb`)

Conclusion: In order to decrypt a password, one would have to be using the right version of BCrypt, have obtained the secret token from the app, and have the encrypted password, and I think that at that point, user passwords are probably the least of your security concerns, so I think its pretty safe.

Comment: Yeah, but where it the salt is stored?